# How to restrict nginx by origin domain or ip?

Tags: nginx

I have two servers.

The first server is my frontend app and it use nginx as proxy reverse.
The second server is my backend app and it use docker. And Docker inside, i use nginx container as proxy reverse.

I want to restrict my backend app to my frontend and my own ip because my backend has admin page.

I tried many ways but no success.

## frontend

```
upstream frontend {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name frontend.com;
    set_real_ip_from frontend_server_ip;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    real_ip_recursive on;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

## Backend

```
upstream backend {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.backend.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
         root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.backend.com;

    location / {
                # it does not work
    #allow front-end-ip;
    #deny all;
    ##end test
  if ($host !~* frontend_url) { #It does not work
    return 403;
   }


        proxy_pass http://backend/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

As you can see, i tied to restrict by domain or ip but it blocks all request and i don't now why.

## UPDATE

Lets say we have two apps(Front and Backend)
the front communicates with the back using rest APIs.
so the front-end server and the back server are independent and my front use nginx and backend use another nginx.
My backend has admin page.
Now i want to restrict my backend app to my frontend app.

```
 allow frontend_ip;
 deny all;
```

if i use the code above in backend nginx, it block all request and i can see 
in the nginx logs.

```
  nginx_1    | frontend_ip-- -- - - [18/Feb/2020:17:41:37 +0000] "api.backend.com" "GET /articles/about/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux x64) node.js/10.17.0 v8/6.8.275.32-node.54" 0.012
nginx_1    | frontend_ip-- -- - - [18/Feb/2020:17:41:37 +0000] "api.backend.com" "GET /articles/about/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux x64) node.js/10.17.0 v8/6.8.275.32-node.54" 0.018
nginx_1    | 2020/02/18 17:41:40 [error] 550#550: *13449 access forbidden by rule, client: 5.51.0.220, server: api.backend.com, request: "GET /articles/about/ HTTP/1.1", host: "api.backend.com", referrer: "https://frontend_url.com/about"
nginx_1    | 5.51.0.220-- -- - - [18/Feb/2020:17:41:40 +0000] "api.backend.com" "GET /articles/about/ HTTP/1.1" 403 555 "https://frontend_url.com/about" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36" 0.000
nginx_1    | 2020/02/18 17:41:40 [error] 550#550: *13449 access forbidden by rule, client: 5.51.0.220, server: api.backend.com, request: "GET /articles/about/ HTTP/1.1", host: "api.backend.com", referrer: "https://frontend_url.com/about"
nginx_1    | 5.51.0.220-- -- - - [18/Feb/2020:17:41:40 +0000] "api.backend.com" "GET /articles/about/ HTTP/1.1" 403 555 "https://frontend_url.com/about" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36" 0.000
```

Comment: In the configuration you posted, the **frontend** is not connecting to the **backend**, but to its own port `4000`.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't undertand because my frontend calls backend api

Comment: The **frontend** has an effective `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000`, so I suppose port `4000` of the frontend is `DNAT`ted to port `443` (?) of the backend? Can you clarify that in the question?

Comment: My frontend and my backend are on two different servers. My frontend calls only backend api. I updated my post

Comment: The request from your frontend IP was not blocked (status `200`). Only the requests from `5.51.0.220` (presumably your browser) were blocked.

Comment: Yes @Piotr, but if 5.51.0.220 is my browser and it return 403. How to manage it?

Comment: You should add an `allow 5.51.0.220;` directive (before the `deny all;`). Apparently your frontend does not just use the backend itself, but asks your browser to connect to it.

Comment: But how do users do it? Each user has their own browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown by the log lines you added the server part of your frontend is not the only one, who needs access to the backend. The client JavaScript on your webpage also accesses the backend.

In such a situation you should create a separate `location` block for your admin page (let's say it is at `https//api.example.com/admin`) and deny access to it to anyone, but yourself:

```
location /admin/ {
    allow your_ip;
    deny all;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```