# how to pass variable between two nginx proxy?

Tags: nginx

I use two servers(proxy_1_front, proxy_2_back) and each of them uses an nginx proxy.
I only want to allow the first server to make calls to the second server

## Proxy_1

```
upstream angular-frontend {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name frontend.com;
    set_real_ip_from frontend-ip;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    real_ip_recursive on;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }
}
```

## Proxy_2

```
upstream drf-backend {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.backend.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
         root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.backend.com;

    location / {

  if ($host != frontend-ip or $http_X_Forwarded_For != frontend-ip) { #Securing server to only work with my firt server


    return 403;
   }


        proxy_pass http://backend/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

But i notice that there are two ips in the logs(proxy_2) which make the same request . The first is the client ip and the second is the proxy_1 ip.
My question is: how to send a single ip from proxy_1 so that i can then check the following condition

```
  if ($host != frontend-ip or $http_X_Forwarded_For != frontend-ip) { #Securing server to only work with my firt server
    return 403;
   }
```

this will allow only allow my frontend application to access my backend apis.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict nginx by origin domain or ip?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003293/how-to-restrict-nginx-by-origin-domain-or-ip)

Comment: No because the first nginx send two ips. If i restrict by ip. it block all request. I need to pass one unique variable between two nginx. And i just check the variable in the second nginx